# Making the player Jump in like a Upper - Right manner in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, jumping

Ok so I'm new to Unity and I am trying to make this simple ball game. Now in a situation I want the ball to jump in a diagonal manner (i.e W + D ). 
Script that I have makes the ball jump only up and not in like a upper right direction. Can some one please suggest some change in the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BasicMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float rotation_Speed = 100;
    public float jump_Height = 1;

    private bool Falling = false;


    void Update ()
    {
        // FOR ROTATION
        float Rotation = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotation_Speed * Time.deltaTime; // USING FORMULA DISTANCE = SPEED * TIME
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * Rotation);  // APPLYING TORQUE TO THE BALL


        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W) && Falling == false ) 
        {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3 (1, 10, 0) * jump_Height;
                Falling = true;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        Falling = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops The Vector3 is actually (0,10,0) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you are doing in more expensive way actually. Well, you should just apply force on `Rigidbody` instead of setting velocity explicitly.

You can improve your script as,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BasicMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float rotation_Speed = 100;
    public float jump_Height = 1;

    private bool Falling = false;

    Rigidbody _rb;
    float _jumpXRatio = 1;
    float _jumpYRatio = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> (); // it will keep reference
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        // FOR ROTATION
        float Rotation = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotation_Speed * Time.deltaTime; // USING FORMULA DISTANCE = SPEED * TIME
        _rb.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * Rotation);  // APPLYING TORQUE TO THE BALL


        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W) && Falling == false ) 
        {
                // Now set ratios and axes according to your needs
                _rb.AddForce (new Vector3 (_jumpXRatio, _jumpYRatio, 0) * jump_Height);
                Falling = true;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        Falling = false;
    }
}
```